# Maintaining same settings.py in Windows virtualenv and heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, virtualenv

Is there a way to maintain same django settings.py in both Heroku and windows local systemI am using postgres database. I believe it is only the DATABASE_URL set as environment variable in Heroku that is making the difference. Is there some way I could make this work in Windows by setting DATABASE_URL in the environment? Or correct if am wrong here. I tried setting the DATABASE_URL in windows by setting:

set DATABASE_URL='postgres://[DB_USER]:[DB_PASS]@localhost:5432/[DBNAME]

But it is not working, I am getting error when I run syncdb - **"ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details."**. below is my settings.py file:

```
            # Django settings for triplanner project.

            DEBUG = True
            TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

            ADMINS = (
                # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
            )

            MANAGERS = ADMINS

            DATABASES = {
                'default': {
                    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
                    'NAME': 'triplanner',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
                    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
                    'USER': 'akk',
                    'PASSWORD': 'admin',
                    'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
                    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
                }
            }

            import dj_database_url
            DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

            SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

            # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
            # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
            ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

            # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
            # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
            # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
            # In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
            TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

            # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
            # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
            LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

            SITE_ID = 1

            # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
            # to load the internationalization machinery.
            USE_I18N = True

            # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
            # calendars according to the current locale.
            USE_L10N = True

            # If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
            USE_TZ = True

            # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
            # Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
            MEDIA_ROOT = ''

            # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
            # trailing slash.
            # Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
            MEDIA_URL = ''

            # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
            # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
            # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
            # Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
            import os
            BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

            STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

            # URL prefix for static files.
            # Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
            STATIC_URL = '/static/'

            # Additional locations of static files
            STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
                # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
                # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
                # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
            )

            # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
            # various locations.
            STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
                'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
            #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
            )

            # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
            SECRET_KEY = 'w+anq)bguzp0j2d-il*2nbvtwj^f1s4_exq@u)d!^z2ccc=)(3'

            # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
            TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
            )

            MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
                'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
                'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
                'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
                'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
                'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
                # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
                # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
            )

            ROOT_URLCONF = 'triplanner.urls'

            # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
            WSGI_APPLICATION = 'triplanner.wsgi.application'

            TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
                # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
                # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
            )

            INSTALLED_APPS = (
                'django.contrib.auth',
                'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                'django.contrib.sessions',
                'django.contrib.sites',
                'django.contrib.messages',
                'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                'registration',
                # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
                # 'django.contrib.admin',
                # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
                # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
            )

            ####### Begin Of Arguments specific to django-registration application ############
            ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
            EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
            DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'akash@localhost.com'
            LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
            ####### End Of Arguments specific to django-registration application ############

            ####### Begin Of Arguments specific to Invitation application ############
            ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
            ACCOUNT_INVITATION_DAYS = 7
            INVITATIONS_PER_USER = 3
            INVITE_MODE = True
            ####### End Of Arguments specific to Invitation application ############
            # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
            # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
            # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
            # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
            # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
            LOGGING = {
                'version': 1,
                'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                'filters': {
                    'require_debug_false': {
                        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
                    }
                },
                'handlers': {
                    'mail_admins': {
                        'level': 'ERROR',
                        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
                    }
                },
                'loggers': {
                    'django.request': {
                        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                        'level': 'ERROR',
                        'propagate': True,
                    },
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically should work. Try setting `DATABASE_URL` in a file called `.env` which you place next to your `Procfile`. Foreman will find it and use it when running your processes. The syntax is simply `DATABASE_URL=...`, without any quotes, and without the word "set", etc.

Comment: In settings.py, the below changes worked:

    DATABASES['default'] =      dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL","'postgres://[DB_USER]:[DB_PASS]@localhost:5432/[DBNAME]))

worked for me. Thanks!